# How implement an interface Generic Method

Tags: java, generics, interface

How can I implement, for example, a String type of a `non-generic-interface` with a `generic method`?

Here is the interface:

```
// non-generic-class
interface I{

    public <T> T doI(T t);

}
```

Comment: the same way the method is defined in the interface, just with method body.

Comment: mmm you are returning the same type provide as parameter. You could modify the object by reference and make doI void???

Comment: good question, I don't know.

Comment: Java use two modes by reference and value. You can use it in in your Interface. HttpServlet.doGet is a good example it's void and the client modify the object by reference

Comment: why *<T>* and *T* for return type of method? I know that the compiler has no issue with that but trying to imagine the requirement for it. could you please explain briefly what needs to be achieved. good question by the way.

Comment: @user3320018 , when you don't declare a class/interface generic, like `interface X<T>` you must declare the `<T>` before the `return` type of the method. Its a specification. I think is some related to "the compiler must know the declaration before use" . And that is a generic method. And you could use like `objectRef.<String>doI("this os cool")`

Comment: @ThufirHawat , to implement such method, I am thinking in the lines of *public <T extends Object> T doI(T t)* in the subclass, and doing that may require creating another type for the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `<T>` in this interface means is that the type `T` passed to the method is the same as the type `T` returned from the method.

Implementation requires some use of the symbol T as if it was a class Like

```
public <T> T doI(T t){
    Object a = t.getClass().newInstance();
    return (T) a;
}
```

You can then call it with something like

```
I obj = getIImplementer ();
String a = obj.doI ("ssssssss");
```

And the compiler knows it can infer the return type from the object type passed.

If you want to implement a specific version you need to put the generic parameter on the interface rather than the method so you can type the implementing class and therefore the method parameter.