# Generic method inside interface

Tags: java, generics, methods, interface

Let's say I have this interface:

```
public interface i{ 
     void setImage(Image image);
}
```

I want that class methods that implements that interface method are allowed to accept as method paramether not only **Image**, but all classes that **extends Image**.

What I need inside the interface is something like:

```
<T extends Image> void setImage(T image);
```

But of course, this is not the right way to do it How should I write a generic method in an **Interface**?

Comment: What do you plan to do that is class-specific? I ask this because taking `Image` as a parameter already does allow for all subclasses of Image.

Comment: The non-generic form already accepts things that extend `Image`.

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618425/how-implement-an-interface-generic-method also (potential dupe) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989740/it-does-not-make-sense-to-have-generic-method-in-interface

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are allowed to declare the method with the generic in the interface:

```
<T extends Image> void setImage(T image);
```

but this actually isn't very much use: the only methods you can invoke on `image` are those defined on `Image`, so you might as well just declare it non-generically:

```
void setImage(Image image);
```

and this will accept parameters of type `Image` or any subclass.

---

Declaring a method-level type variable might be useful if, say, you wanted to return a variable of the same type as the parameter:

```
<T extends Image> T setImage(T image);
```

or if you need to constrain generic parameters to types related to other parameters:

```
<T extends Image> void setImage(T image, List<T> imageList);
```

It wouldn't help you without generic parameters, e.g.

```
<T extends Image> void setImage(T image1, T image2)
```

since you could pass in any two subclasses of `Image`; again, you may as well do it non-generically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
public interface i<M extends Image>{ 
     void setImage(M image);
}
```